# Warning: in_array() null given in PHP function

Tags: php, functions, filters, array

I'm building a metabox gallery in Wordpress for a specific page template. I have the following warning notice in the dashboard:

*Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in...*

The warning is for the code line: `if ( in_array( $post_type, $post_types ) ) {`

```
public function add_meta_box( $post_type ) {

    $post_types = apply_filters( 'sortable_wordpress_gallery_post_types', array( 'post' ) );
    $post_types = apply_filters( 'sortable_wordpress_gallery_' . $this->id .  '_post_types',  $post_types );

    if ( in_array( $post_type, $post_types ) ) {
        add_meta_box(
            $this->id,
            $this->title,
            array( $this, 'render_meta_box_content' ),
            $post_type,
            $this->context,
            $this->priority
            );
    }
}
```

This is the code where I specify the page template where the metabox should be displayed.

```
add_filter( 'sortable_wordpress_gallery_post-metabox_post_types',  'first_gallery_only_on_page' );
function first_gallery_only_on_page( $post_types ) {

  global $post;
  if(!empty($post)) {
    $pageTemplate = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true);
    if($pageTemplate == 'page-coworking.php' ) {

         return array( 'page' );

    }
  }

}
```

I understand that one of my param is null, but I don't find the way to set it before using it. Thank you.

Comment: Your filter should `return $post_types;` at the bottom, to catch the case where $post is empty or you're not on the coworking page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first you have this code

```
// no matter what the value here, you can forget about it (because in the next line of code you assing a new value to the same variable)
$post_types = apply_filters( 'sortable_wordpress_gallery_post_types', array( 'post' ) );

// only this really matters
$post_types = apply_filters( 'sortable_wordpress_gallery_' . $this->id .  '_post_types',  $post_types );
```

The value in the second `$post_types` is what you check.

Now the callback function

You do a check if `$post` is empty, do some code and return an array. But you forgot to return a value if `$post` is not empty.

In fillters the first parameter of the callback function is returned, so in this case right before the closing bracket of the callback function you need to return `$post_types`

Complete example for callback function

```
function first_gallery_only_on_page ($post_types) {
    global $post;

    if (!empty($post)) {
        $pageTemplate = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true);

        if ($pageTemplate == 'page-coworking.php' ) {
            return array( 'page' );
        }
    }

    return $post_types; // add this line
}
```

Comment: You're right! Thank you very much @Buttered_Toast, the warning has disappeared.